# Apper errors and looking strange when opening it via sudo

Tags: debian, package-management, kde, root, mime-types

So I [locked my root account for security purposes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383301/should-i-disable-the-root-account-on-my-debian-pc-for-security).

It seems that for some reason when apper asks for the root password when installing, deinstalling or updating packages it doesn't make use of the `sudo` command (why?!) and hence I get an authentication error when entering my password there. Meaning I have to start apper as root via `sudo apper` to be able to update/de/install packages.

Now the problem I have with that is that I get a bunch of errors in the console when executing either `apper` or `sudo apper` and apper looks really strange and old and all its icons aren't shown.

The errors are:

> [QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382789/qstandardpaths-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-defaulting-to-tmp-runtime-root-when)
>   QCommandLineParser: option not defined: "install-mime-type"
>   QCommandLineParser: option not defined: "install-package-name"
>   QCommandLineParser: option not defined: "install-provide-file"
>   QCommandLineParser: option not defined: "install-catalog"
>   QCommandLineParser: option not defined: "remove-package-by-file"
>   Invalid pixmap specified.
>   QOBject::connect: No such slot
>   MainUi::seetCaption(QString)
>   QObject::connect: (sendern name:
>   'ApperKCM')   void PackageModel::clear()
>   No frame loaded No frame loaded
>   ...
>   void PackageModel::finished()
>   PackageKit::Transaction(0xsomecode)
>   PackageKit::Transaction(0xsamecode)
>   ...

The 2nd time executed that command I got fewer errors and some new ones:

> Reusing existing ksycoca
>   Recreating ksycoca file ("/root/.cache/ksycoca5_..., version id)
>   Still in the time dict (i.e. deleted files) ("apps", "servicetypes", "services")
>   Menu "application-kmenuedit.menu not found.
>   Saving
>   ...
>   QObject::connect: No such slot MainUi::setCaption(QString)
>   QObject::connect: (sender name:  'ApperKCM')

So my question: what do these errors mean - what's causing them? And how to fix them? And how to get apper to look normal when opening it via `sudo` (this probably has to do with these errors).

I'm using Debian 9.1 with KDE and Dolphin.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look his Problem Here: https://wiki.debian.org/sudo, in The Section: *"Problems and tips"*.

"PATH not set" Section ([removed](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo?action=diff&rev2=52&rev1=51)):

> A typical error using sudo to install a package might result in:
>
> ```
> dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
> dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable.
> dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable.
> Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
> ```
>
> The packaged /etc/sudoers file contains this line:
>
> Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"